# word choice - realize notice find out figure out

Tags: word-usage

The other day, I was at the bookstore and I noticed there was a woman surrounded by a large crowd. It was hard to tell what was going on. So, at first, I figured it was an employee handing out free stuff. But when I got a little closer, it looked like she was signing autographs. Since it was a bookstore,

I (knew/noticed/found/found out/figured/figured out/realized) that it could be a famous writer signing books.

I don't want to ask a lot but, could you choose the right word?

And could you let me know which one is right/not right and why and why not?

Comment: They are all *synonyms*, are you looking for the difference? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

They all have slightly different meanings:

**Realize (or realise, UK)** - means you have come to a realisation of something. It is the end of a thought process, but sometimes perhaps an "unintentional" or subconscious thinking. One metaphor sometimes used in place of "a sudden realisation" is "a light-bulb moment".

**Notice** - literally means that you have *seen* something. That can also lead to a realisation of something, but it is not technically the same.

**Find out** - this describes the very deliberate process of discovery. Perhaps researching something.

**Figure out** - would normally be used idiomatically in place of "find out", but I would say it better describes the *thinking* stage of that process whereas "find out" suggests investigation, perhaps going out searching for information. I am a British English speaker, but I am aware that "figure" is used more often and a little more glibly to mean "thought".

As regards which word to use in your sentence - I actually think *none* of them are completely ideal:

> I (knew/noticed/found/found out/figured/figured out/realized) that it could be a famous writer signing books.

This is because you are not identifying the person signing books as a famous writer. In fact the sentence implies that you are not sure, as you say it only "*could be*" a famous writer.

Personally I would say:

> I **wondered if** it could be a famous writer signing books.

But perhaps, considering that "glib" use of "figured" that I mentioned seems to exist in American English, maybe you could say:

> I *figured* that it could be a famous writer signing books.

Or

> I *figured* that it *might* be a famous writer signing books.